# Javascript code returning "Not found" when script is called

Tags: javascript

*Updated with entire code for context*

My code should run the function when the calculate button is pressed ( in this case, I was testing to see if it would display the alert if I check no radio buttons) but instead the page returns "Not found" message.

Now, I'm totally new at this so it's gone over my head as to what is wrong.

Bonus question: Could I have a hint as to how I make my function look at which buttons are selected and make a calculation from that? Example: If I wanted to selected radio button 1 (having a value of 10) and 3 (having a value of 4) the function would add them together to make 14, and so on for whichever choices you select.

```js
function calculation() {
  var cost = 0; //Base cost of flight (one way Economy)
  var radioButton; // A radio button
  var selection = 0; // The selected radio button, 1 to 6 going down.
  for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { // Get the number of the selection (1 to 6)

    radioButton = document.getElementById("destination" + i);
    if (radioButton.checked == true) {
      selection = i;
    }
    // Give Base cost of flight
    if (selection == 1) {
      cost = 229
    } else if (selection == 2) {
      cost = 259
    } else if (selection == 3) {
      cost = 199
    } else if (selection == 4) {
      cost = 179
    } else if (selection == 5) {
      cost = 179
    } else if (selection == 6) {
      cost = 239
    }
    // Check if a flight was not selected and prompt
    else if (selection == 0) {
      alert("Please select a flight.");
    }
    seating = 0;
    for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
      radioButton = document.getElementById("seating" + x);
      if (radioButton.checked == true) {
        seating = radioButton.id;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Hawkins Airlines Fare Calculator</h1>
<p> Complete the form below to calculate the cost of your flight.</p>

<form>
  <p>Route:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="destination1"> Hawkins - Riverdale<br>
  <input type="radio" id="destination2"> Hawkins - Haddonfield<br>
  <input type="radio" id="destination3"> Hawkins - Rockwell<br>
  <input type="radio" id="destination4"> Hawkins - Eagleton<br>
  <input type="radio" id="destination5"> Hawkins - Pawnee<br>
  <input type="radio" id="destination6"> Hawkins - Twin Peaks<br>
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="appliances" id="return">
  <label>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare </label><br>

  <p>Seating class:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="seating1"> First seating<br>
  <input type="radio" id="seating2"> Business seating<br>
  <input type="radio" id="seating3"> Economy seating<br>
  <br>

  <button onclick="calculation()"> Calculate </button>
  <input type="reset" value="Restore Defults">
</form>
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `{` after `for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)`

Comment: `class = radioButton.id;` here, `class` is a reserved word. It'd be better to change that name.

Comment: ^^ consequently, only `radioButton = document.getElementById("destination" + i);` is *in* the loop. All the rest of the code runs when the loop has finished, with `radioButton` set to the last radio button picked up by the loop. You can see this by using the powerful debugger built into your IDE and/or browser: In the browser, for instance, open "dev tools" (usually F12 and/or Ctrl+Shift+I), go to the Sources pane (or similar), and click in the gutter next to the `for` line to set a breakpoint, then click your button and it'll stop on that line. Step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: (my comment above refers to Cerbrus's [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284346/javascript-code-returning-not-found-when-script-is-called#comment102933805_58284346), not second.

Comment: can you provide more from your HTML? so that we can see what you are dealing with

Comment: Please always include all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) in a code snippet so that we can reproduce your issue and provide a working answer.

Comment: If you open your developer tools (F12) in your browser and look at the console tab, you'll see that you have syntax errors in your code that need to be fixed.

Comment: I have updated with the rest of the code for context.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the javascript code. You should not use `class` as a variable and there was a missing `{}` in your first loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <script>
        function calculation() {
            var cost = 0; //Base cost of flight (one way Economy)
            var radioButton; // A radio button
            var selection = 0; // The selected radio button, 1 to 6 going down.
            for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {// Get the number of the selection (1 to 6)
                radioButton = document.getElementById("destination" + i);
                if (radioButton.checked == true) {
                    selection = i;
                }
            }
            if (selection == 1) {
                cost = 229
            } else if (selection == 2) {
                cost = 259
            } else if (selection == 3) {
                cost = 199
            } else if (selection == 4) {
                cost = 179
            } else if (selection == 5) {
                cost = 179
            } else if (selection == 6) {
                cost = 239
            } else if (selection == 0) {
                alert("Please select a flight.");
                return false;
            }
            var seating = 0;
            for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
                radioButton = document.getElementById("seating" + x);
                if (radioButton.checked == true) {
                    seating = x;
                }
            }

            var totalcost = 0;
            if(seating == 0){
                alert("Please select a seat.");
                return false;
            } else if(seating == 1){
                totalcost = cost + (cost * 2);
            } else if(seating == 2){
                totalcost = cost + (cost * 1.5);
            } else if(seating == 3){
                totalcost = cost;
            }


            if(document.getElementById("return").checked){
                totalcost = totalcost*2;
            }
            totalcost = totalcost + cost;
            alert("Total cost: "+totalcost);
        }

    </script>
    <body>
        <h1> Hawkins Airlines Fare Calculator</h1>
        <p> Complete the form below to calculate the cost of your flight.</p>

        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <p>Route:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination1"> Hawkins - Riverdale<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination2"> Hawkins - Haddonfield<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination3"> Hawkins - Rockwell<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination4"> Hawkins - Eagleton<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination5"> Hawkins - Pawnee<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination6"> Hawkins - Twin Peaks<br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="appliances" id="return">
            <label>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare </label><br>

            <p>Seating class:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating1"> First seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating2"> Business seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating3"> Economy seating<br>
            <br>

            <button onclick="calculation()"> Calculate </button>
            <input type="reset" value="Restore Defults">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works pretty well!
Just two things aren't working. The function should not attempt a calculation if nothing is selected. And, the alerts should calculate the total sum of everything selected.

Comment: @BreeSergent updated the code - that should be okay

Comment: Here are the calculations it should make:

Return = x2 of Base price

economy fare = Base price
business class fare = X1.5 of base price
First class fare= X2 Base price

So for example, If I select a flight with a base price of $300 and I'm going return in First class, The alert should say "Total cost is $1500" (300+600+600)